# Custom select labels in admin page

Tags: django

I'm trying to make on my admin page a CharField where I can write custom labels.
Here I have two choices in AVAILABLE_DATES and I want to type custom labels on admin page, because everytime I want to change AVAILABLE DATES I need to go to mymodels.py and change it manually. 


mymodels.py

```
AVAILABLE_DATES=(
    (u'25.01.2015',u'25.01.2015'),
    (u'09.02.2015',u'09.02.2015'),

)


class SignUp(models.Model):
    date=models.CharField(verbose_name='Choose a date',choices=AVAILABLE_DATES,max_length=100)
```

Comment: `choices` can be any iterable, not just list/tuple.  What do you mean by "custom labels"?  How should they change?

Comment: For example, I have a CharField on my admin Page called 'AVAILABLE_DATES' and when I write something on it then values under <select></select> on my page would change.

Comment: Then you should use `ForeignKey` instead of `CharField`.

Comment: How about ModelChoiceField?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Comment: `ModelChoiceField` is the default form representation of model's `ForeignKey`. Believe me, `ForeignKey` is what you need :-) Changeable `choices` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's works.

Custom labels editable from admin panel:

```python
#mymodels.py

class CustomDates(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.date)

class SignUp(models.Model):
    date=models.ForeignKey(CustomDates)
```

```python
#admin.py

class DatesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date = CustomDates

admin.site.register(CustomDates, DatesAdmin)
```